# Blackberry - Runtime for Android apps

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i'm trying to run my android app already Verifyed with the Blackberry Builder Eclipse plugin.
And after eclipse tried the console output is:

```
Failed to install xxxxxxx.apk on device 'localhost:63787!
(null)
Failed to install xxxxxxx.apk on device 'localhost:63787': null
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
Launch canceled!
```

I could run this project 2 months ago, but now i can't and don't understand why?
Please some help!

Comment: Is this on a device or an emulator? Have you tried checking if any other processes are using that port? Try and uninstall the app if already installed on the device.

Comment: is on device z10 and q10. There is no other processes using the port. And i restore the phone to factory configurations. So the app it's not installed. Thanks for answered!